# MPAndroidChart marker is cut of in right or left screen

Tags: android, marker, mpandroidchart

how to set margin or identify if marker display in right or left screen, cause my marker is cut off when show in right or left of screen.
[image: linechart] 
i want like this image below if i click value in the left or right not cut off like image above
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question but for people who were struggling like me, you can use `lineChart.setViewPortOffsets(...)` method to play around with the paddings. (Keep in mind that you also need to update the margins of your chart so it doesn't shrink)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set margin for chart class

by using

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);
        charId.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


   android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
```

Comment: it's not like that, what i want is for marker in LineChart if it show value in the right or left screen i doesn't cut off like in picture above, only for marker not the entire LineChart layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint()` of `MarkerView` and calculate the marker position using `chartView.width`. You need to set chart view to `MarkerView.chartView` before calculation.

This worked for me -

```
override fun getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(posX: Float, posY: Float): MPPointF {
    if (posX > chartView.width - width) {
        offset.x = (-width).toFloat()
    } else {
        offset.x = (-(width / 2)).toFloat()
    }

    offset.y = -(height / 2).toFloat()

    return offset
}
```